# How to output taxCategory in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to test for a taxCategory within Craft Commerce and finding it awkward to do so. I can't see much in the docs, but have managed to put this together:

```
{% if product.taxCategory | length %}
    {% for taxCategory in product.taxCategory %}
        {# loops through the taxCategory with the first string being the id, #}
        {# the second the name and the third string seems to be the slug #}
        {% if loop.index == 3 and taxCategory == "withVat" %}
            +VAT
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't seem very elegant. Any suggestions? The docs example probably needs updating, I think, because:

```
{% for taxCategory in craft.commerce.taxCategories %}
    {{ taxCategory.id }} - {{ taxCategory.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

...outputs: "Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a string variable"

Comment: ask luke holder on the craft commerce slack channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your first bit of code by using:

`{{ product.taxCategory.name == 'withVat' ? '+VAT' }}`

The reason you get the error with your second bit of code is because `craft.commerce.taxCategories` is only an array of Tax Category names. Only the models of each Tax Category would have properties such as `.id` and `.name`

Answer (score 1):

A full `Commerce_TaxCategoryModel` array will be returned in Craft Commerce 1.2

If you would like this functionality now, please replace the `getTaxCategories()` function in the `plugins/commerce/variables/CommerceVariable.php` file with this replacement function:

```
public function getTaxCategories()
{
    $taxCategories = craft()->commerce_taxCategories->getAllTaxCategories();

    // Need to put the methods into an array keyed by method ID for backwards compatibility.
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($taxCategories as $model)
    {
        $newArray[$model->id] = $model;
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Ooh. Thanks Luke! Will wait until 1.2 and make a point to update my templates.

Comment: Any idea when 1.2 will be released @lukeholder?